HTMX Django not activating on form fields
I have a form with 3 select options, when the user selects the first one i updated the second with htmx, when the used selects the second i would like to update the third the same way. However, the third doesn't initialize the htmx request.
Here is my django form:

    purchased_by = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        label="Empresa compradora",
        queryset=OurCompany.objects.filter(definecat=2).order_by('name'),
        widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control',
                                   'hx-get': reverse_lazy('compras:oc_update_local'),
                                   'hx-trigger': 'change',
                                   'hx-target': '#div_local',
                                   'hx-swap': 'outerHTML'}),
    )

    delivery_location = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        label="Local de Entrega/Obra",
        queryset=Empreendimento.objects.all().order_by('name'),
        widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control',
                                   'hx-get': reverse_lazy('compras:oc_update_cc'),
                                   'hx-trigger': 'change',
                                   'hx-target': '#div_cc',
                                   'hx-swap': 'outerHTML'}),
    )

This is my views:

def oc_update_local(request):
    company = request.GET.get('purchased_by')
    empresa = OurCompany.objects.get(pk=company)
    if empresa.definecat == 1:
        if empresa.name[:5] == "Cabiu":
            company = OurCompany.objects.get(name='Cabiunas Inc')
            empreendimentos = Empreendimento.objects.filter(
                company=company).order_by('name')
        elif empresa.name[:5] == "Coque":
            company = OurCompany.objects.get(
                name='Coqueiral Agropecuaria Matriz')
            empreendimentos = Empreendimento.objects.filter(
                company=company).order_by('name')
    else:
        empreendimentos = Empreendimento.objects.filter(
            company=company).order_by('name')
    return render(request, "compras/partials/oc_update_local.html", {"empreendimentos": empreendimentos})


def oc_update_cc(request):
    local = request.GET.get('delivery_location')
    ccs = CentroCusto.objects.filter(imovel=local).order_by('name')
    return render(request, "compras/partials/oc_update_cc.html", {"ccs": ccs})

And this is my html template:
<div class="form-row">
            <div class="form-group col-3">
                {{ form.purchased_by | as_crispy_field }}
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-4" id="div_local">
                {{ form.delivery_location | as_crispy_field }}
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-4" id="div_cc">
                {{ form.cc |as_crispy_field }}
            </div>
        </div>

And i have a partial for each update, but the second never triggers.
Thanks for the help
only one htmx request on browser happening

Can you include the `oc_update_local.html partial', please.
